# Models for time events

Tags: r, survival

For recurrent time events exist recurrent survival analysis or frailty models.

Is there any diffence between [frailty models](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/frailtypack/frailtypack.pdf) and [frailty models for survival analysis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/frailtySurv/frailtySurv.pdf)?